# How can I improve express.js error stack trace?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using Node with Express as an API. Currently this is the output if there is an unexpected error thrown:

```
  "stack": "APIError: test error\n    at new ExtendableError 
(/home/user/workspace/test-api/server/helpers/error.ts:25:11)\n    at new APIError 
(/home/user/workspace/test-api/server/helpers/error.ts:41:5)\n
    at app.use (/home/user/workspace/test-api/config/express.ts:112:24)\n
    at Layer.handle_error (/home/user/workspace/test-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)\n
    at trim_prefix (/home/user/workspace/test-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)\n    at /home/user/workspace/test-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7\n
    at Function.process_params (/home/user/workspace/test-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)\n
    at next (/home/user/workspace/test-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)\n
    at Layer.handle_error (/home/user/workspace/test-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:67:12)\n
    at trim_prefix (/home/user/workspace/test-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)\n
    at /home/user/workspace/test-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7\n
    at Function.process_params (/home/user/workspace/test-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)\n
    at next (/home/user/workspace/test-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)\n 
    at Layer.handle_error (/home/user/workspace/test-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:67:12)\n
    at trim_prefix (/home/user/workspace/test-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)\n 
    at /home/user/workspace/test-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7\n
    at Function.process_params (/home/user/workspace/test-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)\n 
   at next (/home/user/workspace/test-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)\n 
   at /home/user/workspace/test-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15\n
   at Immediate.next (/home/user/workspace/test-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:260:14)\n
   at Immediate.<anonymous> (/home/user/workspace/test-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15)\n 
   at runCallback (timers.js:812:20)\n 
   at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)\n
   at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)",
```

I would love it if I can display the file, linenumber and function where this happened but I have no clue how to do this.

Can anyone help or point me in the right direction?

For reference, you can see the boilerplate my project is based on [here](https://github.com/Christilut/node-modern-boilerplate). Express setup can be found in [config/express.ts](https://github.com/Christilut/node-modern-boilerplate/blob/master/config/express.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [source-map-support](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-support). Your stack trace is actually showing you the file and line number of the code that triggered an error but it seems to show it on **transpiled code**. Install the package and call `install()` inside your entry file:

```
$ npm install --save-dev source-map-support

// entry.ts
require('source-map-support').install();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried it but it seems to have no effect, output is the exact same. Typescript seems to be making sourcemap files.
Maybe it has to do with the async nature of Express?